# How can i give only view permission for user in django admin?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-users

I have a table called x which contains some information. In that table i have an EDIT and DELETE Links. Now what i want is if i login as an admin i want to enable those two links and if i login as a user i don't want them to be enabled and if that user add any info in that table,for that particular info only EDIT and DELETE links has to be enabled(where user should not have the access to EDIT or DELETE the other info)
Is there any way?if so please mention here.

Thankyou

Comment: This is available in Django 2.1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#what-s-new-in-django-2-1

Answer (score 0):

Define change and delete permission checking the is_staff status inside your admin class

```
def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        return False

def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        return False
```

Comment: Did some modifications in your code and works fine for delete.
But when i click on edit it is editing

Comment: when user have status of "non-staff", they cannot enter the admin

Comment: that does not make everything into "view only mode". It will only make them unable to go to each object admin page to see the data (and cannot delete)